# Pubby displays question marks instead of the actual namespaces

Tags: apache, tomcat, rdf, sparql, linked-data

Some URIs that represent namespaces do not appear in Pubby Linked Data Frontend: there is just a question mark (?) sign where the namespace should be even though when you click on that URL it will take you to the right page.

I initially assumed that Pubby doesn't find the prefixes.ttl file, but in that case the link would have also not worked and I would have also seen an error (which I saw in other instances)... Obviously something else is causing this. Does anyone has any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had the same issue, and we fixed it by adding the prefixes in Pubby's config.ttl file, just before everything else. For example:

```
 ##Declare all your prefixes here
 @prefix geosparql: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>.
 @prefix geo-ont: <http://www.oeg-upm.net/ontologies/geo#>.

 ##Pubby config.ttl file starts here
 # Server configuration section
 <> a conf:Configuration;
     # Project name for display in page titles
     conf:projectName "nameOfOurProject";
     # Homepage with description of the project for the link in the page header
     conf:projectHomepage <http://projectHomePage.com>;
 ....
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. [It seems](http://www.dr0i.de/sysop/2011/08/03/sparql_endpoint_interface_pubby_0_3_3_missing_prefix.html) that the last version of pubby (0.3.3) does not use the prefixes defined inside the **config.ttl** file.

The solution is to use the config option `conf:usePrefixesFrom <file.rdf>;`

But, take care. [It seems](http://www.dr0i.de/sysop/2011/08/03/sparql_endpoint_interface_pubby_0_3_3_missing_prefix.html) that you can not link to a file (despite its signature) but **only** to a URL. For instance:

```
conf:usePrefixesFrom <http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~finin//prefixes.n3>;
```

This was the solution in my case.